# Unable to execute Powershell from C# Application

Tags: c#, powershell-3.0

I've added in the reference to the Powershell dll (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\System.Management.Automation.dll); I've also removed that reference and opened up the Project File and added in `<Reference Include="System.Management.Automation />`. However, neither of these work, I always get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace Powershell_Execution
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (String str in PowerShell.Create().AddScript("Get-Process").AddCommand("Out-String").Invoke<String>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }



            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Everything I've run across just said to add the `<Reference Include="System.Management.Automation />`, but that just produces the same runtime error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strong Name Validation Failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403731/strong-name-validation-failed)

Comment: Try using Fuslogvw.exe tool to view binding issue error messages, could be due to incompatible key:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @LeslieDavies unless I am misinterpreting how to use fuslogvw, nothing appears in the application logs when I run fuslogvw.

Comment: Run with admin privileges and go to Settings and select "Log all binds to disk" or "Log bind failures to disk"

Comment: @LeslieDavies Whoops didn't have "Log all binds to disk" checked, now stuff is popping up. I'll compare keys now thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your code work fine on my PC. I'm not sure what the problem obviously. 
But [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e08ec67e-3f1d-41d8-9f5f-1d4ce3c5249c/strong-name-validation-failed-in-win-7-64) , [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shitals/archive/2008/05/01/8446582.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100006/sgen-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-exception-from-hresult-0x801314)

They solve your problem