# System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2'

Tags: vb.net

I am currently working on Outlook 2013 Addin Projects using visual studio 2013 and Visual Basic .Net. However, when I try to connect to DB2 Database. It shows that the dll files that I added into the project reference cannot be loaded.

What I do is add a new panes with a button in outlook which will look a windows form in outlook when the button is clicked. Onload the form, it will connect to DB2 and the below error message occur

---

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)
File name: 'IBM.Data.DB2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208'

=== Pre-bind state information ===

LOG: DisplayName = IBM.Data.DB2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208
 (Fully-specified) 
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/D0259/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/OutlookAddIn3/OutlookAddIn3/bin/Debug/ 
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL

## **Calling assembly : OutlookAddIn3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.**

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.

LOG: No application configuration file found.

LOG: Using host configuration file:

LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: IBM.Data.DB2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/D0259/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/OutlookAddIn3/OutlookAddIn3/bin/Debug/IBM.Data.DB2.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131045). Probing terminated.

---

Other windows form project using the same dll is working. Really need some advice on this. Anyone face this error before? Viewers' help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the DLL specific to x86 or x64 when your computer is not?

Comment: Thanks sparkysword for your reply, but I have managed to solve the problem from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100006/sgen-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-exception-from-hresult-0x801314/13009177#13009177

Comment: I have to install Microsoft SDK and perform sn.exe