# Error: Strong name validation failed for application

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, registry, .net-assembly

I'm facing issue `An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Unknown Module. Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceName, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5bfb54a682cb6e6d' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)`. I've tried many ways like below

1. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8.1 Tools\x64\sn.exe" -Vr C:\Code\cfc\bin\ServiceName.dll`
2. `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\ServiceName,5bfb54a682cb6e6d]`
3. `Sn -Vr * in VS Commandprompt`

All these tries were failed. Kindkly help me to solve this issue. struggling since 2 days. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: In [SGEN : error : Could not load file or assembly (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100006/sgen-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-exception-from-hresult-0x801314) methods tried?

Comment: Thanks! @wenbingeng-MSFT. To find `sn.exe` just ran `c:\Program Files(x86)>dir /s sn.exe`. It will gives list `sn`'s. And to the respective directories then executed `sn -Vr *,5bfb54a682cb6e6d`. In my case I've two `sn.exe`'s. It fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! @[wenbingeng-MSFET](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20528460/wenbingeng-msft)
to find `sn.exe` just ran `c:\Program Files(x86)>dir /s sn.exe`. It will gives list `sn`'s. And went to the respective directories then executed `sn -Vr *,5bfb54a682cb6e6d`. In my case I've two `sn.exe`'s. It fixed my issue.